# What's your favorite code golf video?

Tags: discussion, code-golf

Do you have a favorite code-golf video? Maybe someone golfing before it was cool? Or because it was a way to solve a problem?

Comment: I didn't know there were code golf videos...

Comment: You need to define what you mean by "code golf video"

Answer (score 2):

Here's my favorite, Guy Steele reverse-engineering his old program golfed to fit on a single punch card.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dPK6t7echuA